# Making a chessboard using a picturebox and rectangles, how to initialize?

Tags: c#, picturebox, multidimensional-array, rectangles

I am making a C# chess game so I can practice coding with the language some more. I am using windows forms and I use pieces that are 45x45 .png icons. I have made my picturebox so that each location on the board is 50x50 pixels, making the picturebox/board a 400x400 square. What I would like to figure out is, how to initialize the board so I can move pieces using a 2D array of type Rectangle. That way, each location on the board is a rectangle defined as 50x50 square. My code so far, if I'm missing something important, let me know:

```
class Board//this class represents the board 
{
    private Rectangle[,] chessBoard = new Rectangle[8, 8]; //a 2d array of rectangles


    public void initBoard()//this method will initialize the picturebox/board
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
            {
                chessBoard[x, y] = new Rectangle(x * 50, y * 50, 50, 50);


            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Okay...what's your problem?

Comment: are you looking for affirmation? If so, that is some superb code

Comment: moving this to an answer for more room...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that while your method will likely get you there, most chess games would not use separate pngs for the images, rather you would have a single image with a 2x6 tile matrix and use offsets into the image to select the right tile. You could store the board as a one dimensional array of 64 elements. Its default starting arrangement could be something like...

```
board = [00,01,02,03,04,02,01,00,
         05,05,05,05,05,05,05,05,
         -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
         -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
         -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
         -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
         15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,
         10,11,12,13,14,12,11,10]
```

where -1 is a blank square and 00-15 are offset indexes into pieces image. as in:

```
00 10 = wr br
01 11 = wk bk
02 12 = wb bb
03 13 = wq bq
04 14 = wK bK
05 15 = wp bp
```

when a player makes a move you simply call a method to determine if the move is legal, if so is the destination occupied? capture! else set board[destination] = board[origin], set board[origin] = -1.

might need to double check me on the positions for K and Q, hope i'm making sense :)

Comment: Thanks, note that you maintain the board state simply by specifying the index into pieces.bmp. for each element in board[]. I have such an image somewhere if you would like me to look. Also, yea it looks like the Q's and K's are right in that matrix. I checked my chessboard :P Also note that you can ignore the leading 0 and use 1-5, just make sure your rect fills in the leading zero for the offset.